# Any suggestion for implementing css framework with Angular spa to provide white labeling?

Tags: angular, sass, white-labelling

Very new to angular world so apology is this sounds immature.

We are in process of converting serverside web application to Angular spa. This application is highly customizable and provides white labeling to clients. Are there any open source css frameworks that would support this design ?

Comment: Define what you do with this white labeling?

Comment: Basically custom dynamic css. So any client can choose background color, font color throughout the website. They can save these preferences in their account.